# php docs return "permission denied" on `require '/root/vendor/autload.php'`

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm really struggling here. I'm just trying to output the contents of a MongoDB collection through a php page; that's it. However, I can't successfully connect to my MongoDB after reading through multiple tutorials.

I learned connecting to your MongoDB through Composer is a viable option.

So I followed this tutorial to install Composer:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04

1.

```
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
```

2.

```
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

3.

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

According to [this tutorial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php), I now need to enter `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in my php file. "No such file or directory." Alright, so I run `sudo find / -name autoload.php` and locate `autoload.php` in `/root/vendor/autload.php`. So I end up with the following php file:

```
<?php
require '/root/vendor/autoload.php'; // Composer autoloader

use MongoDB\Driver\Manager as Mongo;

$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$collection = $mongo->blogDB->posts;
$result = $collection->find()->toArray();

print_r($result);

?>
```

But upon execution of the php file, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: require(/root/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/mySite/read.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/root/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/mySite/read.php on line 2
```

I tried `sudo chmod o+w /root/vendor/` to no avail. Can I simply safely move the `autoload.php` to a new location without corrupting Composer configurations? Where can I move it to?

I thought of uninstalling/reinstalling Composer from scratch (this time within an administrator account instead of within the root account like last time), but `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove composer` fails with the error `Package 'composer' is not installed, so not removed` which I suppose makes sense, since I didn't install it through `apt`.

Comment: try require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Where did you run `composer require mongodb/mongodb`, in what directory? If you run that in the root of your project (that is where you need to run it...), you will get a `vendor/` directory in your project.

Comment: ok I have `require_once DIR .'/vendor/autoload.php'`. Errors: `Use of undefined constant DIR - assumed 'DIR' ... on line 2`. `require_once(DIR/vendor/autload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: It's `__DIR__`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @jeroen - Ah, woops. Thank you. I had not run `composer require mongodb/mongodb` in the project directory... Now I'm back to the error I got before I started this Composer madness which is `Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$blogDB in /var/www/html/mySite/read.php on line 10`. It's not recognizing my database?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongodb but you will probably get an answer here if you post a question (or modify this one...) describing this specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I seem to have solved the issue by changing `$collection = $mongo->blogDB->posts;` to `$collection = new MongoDB\Collection($mongo, "blogDB", "posts");` according to this underappreciated SO answer: https://superuser.com/a/1089721/737983

Answer (score -1):

Give permission to this path : "root/vendor/autoload.php"

Give permission 777

And used "require_once" instead of "require".

This is error because not given permission of file read to this folder.

once give permission then try again. Hopefully code will work